# Basic example of OAuth authorization to upload YouTube video using latest API 1.7+++

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

So the latest beta update looks totally different in terms of OAuth integration and I would love a little bit of guidance on getting it working. The samples posted online are all outdated at this point. The BaseCleintServiceInitializer takes different data than it used to.

var youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {

});

Would love some insight in how to populate this thing assume I have a refresh Token, oauth clientid and oauth secret.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look in our [OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) wiki page, and also in the [Drive API sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/Drive.Sample) (which is similar to YouTube).

You should also consider subscribing to the [announcements blog](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com) to get the latests updates on the library's releases.